# Bluetooth dongle not working with Ubuntu 20.04, detected by phone bluetooth but can't pair?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, dongle

My laptop is Dell Latitude E5570, it doesn't have Bluetooth so I bought an external Bluetooth dongle (CSR 4.0). After plugging the dongle Ubuntu keeps searching for devices. Sometimes it can't detect my phone, but even when it does I can't pair it with the phone.

I've windows OS on the same laptop I tried the dongle with the same phone and it worked fine, the problem happens on Ubuntu only.

Aren't all dongles compatible with Ubuntu?
I don't know exactly what I should do, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Yes, pretty much all USB Bluetooth dongles in the market have native support in any major Linix distro, that's not the problem. The problem can be with yours being defective or some problem with the device you're trying to pair it with. That the detection seems intermittent suggests the latter. Please [edit] the question and give more details, namely which phone are you trying to connect to and whether or not you already tested the dongle with other computers successfully and the same for the phone itself.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question could you please recheck?

Comment: Since this is a dual-boot have you disabled Fast Startup in Windows? It's a must when dual-booting and it can cause situations like this or having some hardware not detected at all when rebooting from Windows to Ubuntu. Try that - disable Fast Startup and shutdown - before anything else.

Comment: I did as you advised but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you booting Ubuntu with the BT dongle connected? Try connecting it after. If the problem persists I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work, thank you very much for your time